# Append javascript/html to page when navigating from a different page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alright, first off this is not a malicious question I'm asking. I have no intentions of using any info for ill gains.

I have an application that contains an embedded browser. This browser runs within the application's process, so I can't access it via Selenium WebDriver or anything like that. I know that it's possible to dynamically append scripts and html to loaded web pages via WebDriver, because I've done it.

In the embedded browser, I don't have access to the pages that get loaded. Instead, I can create my own html/javascript pages and execute them, to manipulate the application that houses the browser. I'm having trouble manipulating the existing pages within the browser.

Is there a way to dynamically add javascript to a page when you navigate to it and have it execute right after the page loads?

Something like

page1.navigateToUrl(executeThisScriptOnLoad)
page2 then executes the passed script.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is not possible to do it without knowledge of destination site. Although you can send data to the site and then use eval() function to evaluate sent data on destination page.

Comment: Well, I can view the source after it loads. I'm just not sure what to do other than grab all the html, append my stuff, then send that back to the browser. I'm sure that would fail though.